# Android Studio simple Unit Test not working

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, junit4

I'm trying to do a simple unit test in AndroidStudio and it is not working. I have tried to follow a lot of tutorials but no sucess until now.

When I run the test, this error message is showed:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method setUp in android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 not mocked.
```

My test class:

```
public class MainActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

    public MainActivity activity;

    public MainActivityTest() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        activity = getActivity();
    }

    @Test
    public void testApp() throws Exception {
        assertTrue(true);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
        activity.finish();
    }
}
```

MainActivity.class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

build.gradle(app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.helloworld.tripbudget"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+"
    compile files('libs/ormlite-android-4.49-SNAPSHOT.jar')
    compile files('libs/ormlite-core-4.49-SNAPSHOT.jar')
}
```

Comment: I have not played with the new unit testing stuff yet, but I would be somewhat surprised if `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` worked with it. Beyond that, take a look at the "Method ... not mocked" section in the unit testing docs: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support

Comment: It is better to describe the solution in the answer box provided and then select "accepted". This is preferable to editing the question which does not cause the question to be recorded as complete.

Answer (score 1):

OP found the answer himself:

> Add the code below to build.gradle:
>
> ```
> android {
>     // ...
>     testOptions { 
>         unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> [Reference](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support)

Comment: No, that answer doesn't always help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use JUnit4 as following to test your activity:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public final class MainActivityTest {

   @Rule public final ActivityRule<MainActivity> mainActivity = new ActivityRule<>(MainActivity.class);

   @Test 
   public void testApp() {
      mainActivity.someFunction(); 
   }
}
```

Comment: This is only applicable to Instrumentation tests, not JVM tests.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest not extending ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2, using Junit 4.

For examples refer to https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html.

Also, for mocking classes Mockito has proved to be very beneficial.

If you need to mock static classes Power Mock works very well with Junit and Mockito https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/GettingStarted.

Hope this helps!